# Programmatic iPod Backup on Linux

Tags: linux, backup, ipod

Are there any publicly available libraries or APIs out there on Ubuntu that allow me to programmatically archive the contents of my iPod? If no library or API exists, what alternative options do I have for saving the contents of my iPod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/about.html) can do it.  Looking over its [source code](http://sourceforge.net/svn/?group_id=67873) might give you what you're looking for.